# How to display URL parameters in PHP script?

Tags: php, url, substring

I want to redirect my browser to a PHP page such that when the page loads, it will display to the user a substring of the current URL.

For example, let's say I have a page called substring.php.

My browser forwards me to:

http://www.example.com/substring.php?oauth_token=123456

Is it possible to write some PHP code that will then display to the user, "123456"?

If so, can anyone help me on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['oauth_token'];
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

All the query parameters in the URL will be inside the [superglobal $_GET](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array, so you could simply do this:

```
echo $_GET['oauth_token'];
```

BE forewarned that if you're going to output anything that comes in from a URL (ie. user input), you should make sure to sanitize it properly for output.  In this case, [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) would be prudent:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['oauth_token']);
```

Comment: Or you could just validate $_GET['oauth'] which looks like it should be a ^[0-9]+$

Comment: Yes, you could.  I wouldn't trust them to not change the OAuth specs in the future to include hashes, but you could always read the docs to determine what it should be at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just use the `$_GET` superglobal? It stores the contents of the query string part of the URI as an associative array:

```
echo $_GET['oauth_token'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the value of `oauth_token` via the `$_GET` superglobal array:

```
echo $_GET['oauth_token'];
```

Of course you should use caution when outputting data you get as input from a user, but that's how it works in short.